# lucene.net search query with no spaces

Tags: full-text-search, lucene.net

I need to search through lucene.net document contains spaces between letters.

example

Document 1: 54 658 1 22

Document 2: 54658 122

Document 3: 5 4658122

Query: 54658122

I need to return all documents that contain the query in the example is all the documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When storing the data in the Lucene index, store a document field where the spaces have been removed from the source data - and index that field.  When searching, strip the spaces and search on the field without spaces.  If the spaces are important in the output, I recommend you also the original data in a separate field of the Lucene document.  That way, you can use it for user display after finding the documents with the other field.